# Set IsMouseOver property for the entire control and not on the DrawingData

Tags: xml, wpf, path, area, ismouseover

I am drawing a triangle using a Path, and the `IsMouseOver` property is true only if the mouse pointer is over the triangle. I would like it to be True also when the pointer is over the background of path (transparent). How can I obtain this result?

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"/>
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF9C9C9C"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FFBDBDBD"/>
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect x:Name="DropShadowEffect" BlurRadius="12" Color="#FF9C9C9C" ShadowDepth="0"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Path Margin="6,0,0,0" StrokeThickness="0" Width="35" Height="17" Data="M0,0 L8,5, 0,10 Z"/>
```

Comment: As you can see from your very varied answers, nobody really has a clear idea on what you want. This is simply because you didn't provide a clear description of your requirements. In future, perhaps you could ask your questions better?

Comment: I would make a button with Path inside, and when the mouse pointer is over the complete area of the path then : - the style of the Path is redefined and the mouse pointer become a hand.
Now, I managed to change style anywhere in the area but the hand pointer is enabled only over the path :/

PS : I'm sorry but I don't speak english very well

Comment: *I'm sorry but I don't speak english very well*... don't worry, your English is good. You just didn't provide enough information before. I'll see if I can take another look later.

Comment: Thanks, I try to be as clear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you have not asked the correct question? You showed your code (which works just fine) and said

> I would like [the `IsMouseOver` property to be] True also when the pointer is over the background of path

The `IsMouseOver` property *is* `true` when you put the mouse over the centre (where the `Background` is) of the `Path`. However, your title says

> Set IsMouseOver property for the entire control and not on the DrawingData

which is of course, something very different (and a good reason to read over your question before posting it). If you want to have the `Path.Effect` change when you put your mouse over the *entire control* then you simply have to write a `Style` that accesses that control instead. Again, you failed to let us know what type that control might be, so I'll just assume that it is a `Window`. Try this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Path}">
    <Setter Property="Stretch" Value="Uniform"/>
    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF9C9C9C"/>
    <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
            AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FFBDBDBD"/>
            <Setter Property="Effect">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DropShadowEffect x:Name="DropShadowEffect" BlurRadius="12" 
                        Color="#FF9C9C9C" ShadowDepth="0"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If that is still not what you're after, then perhaps it would be an idea to be more specific about what you do want.

---

UPDATE >>>

Now that you've explained that the `Path` is in a `Button`, I can suggest that you simply add a `Style` for the `Button` to change the `Cursor`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: It works but only for the Fill property and the DropShadow effect, the cursor setter is    always applied if the pointer is over triangle :/

Comment: Did you have a requirement to change the cursor? I can't see one. As already mentioned (and ignored by you), you need to explain *exactly* what you want... but it's up to you.

Comment: Does this second `Trigger` now fulfil your requirements?

Comment: Is not a button, but is used like a button !

Comment: You said *I would make a button with Path inside*... so if you can't ask what you actually want, then I give up... I'm not going to waste any more time with you.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to place a border around the path, and then bind to the border's IsMouseOver property instead of the path's. For this to work, the border's background has to be explicitly set to "Transparent" (or whatever color you like).

Place a border around the path:

```
<Border x:Name="Border" Background="Transparent" Margin="6,0,0,0" Width="17" Height="17">
    <Path StrokeThickness="0" Data="M0,0 L8,5, 0,10 Z"/>
</Border>
```

Then bind to the border's IsMouseOver property instead of the path's:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=Border}" Value="True">
```

Answer (score 0):

Since path is a kind of shape so the drawn shape is the region which triggers mouse move all other events are passed to the control below

I tried to achieve the same using a different approach

style

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" x:Key="icon">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF9C9C9C"/>
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Border Background="Transparent">
                        <Path Stretch="Uniform" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="6,0,0,0" StrokeThickness="0" Data="{Binding Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFBDBDBD"/>
                <Setter Property="Effect">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DropShadowEffect x:Name="DropShadowEffect" BlurRadius="12" Color="#FF9C9C9C" ShadowDepth="0"/>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

usage

```
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource icon}" Width="35" Height="17" Content="M0,0 L8,5, 0,10 Z"/>
```

in the style above i add a border with transparent background which effectively creates a transparent region for mouse events thus will be able to capture mouse move over full control